# iOS - My code of web Service is not working in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

I'm new on iOS. I have some experiences in Android. I have a problem with using web service in Swift. I googled very much but i can't be success. I use Swift 3.0 and iOS 10.1. I have some information about web service in iOS because of researching very much, and then, i wrote this code. But the label, lblSonuc, is already "Label". I haven't true result unfortunately.

```
var mutableData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData.init();
var currentElementName: NSString = "";

@IBAction func btnDeneme(_ sender: Any) {
    let soapMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/\"><Celsius>10</Celsius></CelsiusToFahrenheit></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"

    let url = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit"

    let urlStr = NSURL(string: url)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlStr as! URL)

    let msgLength = soapMessage.characters.count

    request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    request.addValue(String(msgLength), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = soapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)

    let connection = NSURLConnection.init(request: request as URLRequest, delegate: self)


}

private func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: URLResponse!) {
    mutableData.length = 0;
}


private func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: Data!) {
    mutableData.append(data)
    lblSonuc.text = String(describing: data)    }



func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){
    let response = NSString(data: mutableData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    lblSonuc.text = response as String?
    //let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: mutableData as Data)
    //xmlParser.delegate = self
    //xmlParser.parse()
    //xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true;
```

Comment: I tried to post your example with a SOAP client and I got a failure of "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit". try introducing the event connection(_:didFailWithError:) to see what error you got

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you are making 2 main mistakes here. First, you need to "GET" the variable in your soapMessage via http. You are doing this:

```
let soapMessage: "soap"
let msgLength = soapMessage.characters.count
NSLog(msgLength)
// msgLength is equal to 4 because it has 4 characters!
```

You need to put it in the correct content, then request the data from the database, website, project or what ever you want to pull the data from.

Here is how you can "POST" something in Swift 3 for example:

```
let URLThatYouWantToRequest = NSURL(string: "https://website-address.com/something")!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URLThatYouWantToRequest as URL)
request.httpBody = "item1=value1&item2=value2".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

You can also receive data like this:

```
let URLThatYouWantToRequest = NSURL(string: "https://website-address/something")!
let getRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URLThatYouWantToRequest as URL)
 getRequest.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: getRequest as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    let soapMessage = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let msgLength = soapMessage.characters.count
    NSLog(msgLength)
   }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

To issue Soap 1.1 request:

```
let celcius = 10.0

let bodyString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
    "<soap:Body>" +
    "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://www.w3schools.com/xml/\">" +
    "<Celsius>\(celcius)</Celsius>" +
    "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>" +
    "</soap:Body>" +
    "</soap:Envelope>"

var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = bodyString.data(using: .utf8)
request.setValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("http://www.w3schools.com/xml/CelsiusToFahrenheit", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print("network error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    let parser = XMLParser(data: data)
    parser.delegate = self
    guard parser.parse() else {
        print("parsing error: \(parser.parserError)")
        return
    }

    // if we've gotten here, update the UI

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let fahrenheitValue = self.fahrenheitValue {
            self.lblSonuc.text = "\(fahrenheitValue)"
        } else {
            self.lblSonuc.text = "No fahrenheit value found?!?"
        }
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Note:

1. Don't use `NSURL` or `NSMutableURLRequest` anymore. Use `URL` and `URLRequest` directly.
2. Don't use the deprecated `NSURLConnection` any more. Use `URLSession`. (It's actually easier.)
3. If you're going to make SOAP request, you'll have to parse XML response, e.g.:

   ```
   var fahrenheitValue: Double?
   var elementValue: String?
   ```

   and

   ```
   extension ViewController: XMLParserDelegate {

       func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String] = [:]) {
           if elementName == "CelsiusToFahrenheitResult" {
               elementValue = ""
           }
       }

       func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
           elementValue? += string
       }

       func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
           if elementName == "CelsiusToFahrenheitResult" {
               fahrenheitValue = Double(elementValue!)
               elementValue = nil
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. On the http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit page, they show you what the body and headers of the request need to look like. When I used those above, it worked fine.

   The only thing is that you don't have to set the `Content-Length` header, as `URLSession` does that for you.
5. Make sure you have error handling, detecting network and/or parsing errors, like shown above. Without looking at the error objects, you're flying blind.
6. The only trick is that you have to edit your `Info.plist` to permit non-https request, e.g. edit the source of the `Info.plist` and add the following `key`/`dict` pair:

   ```
   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
   <dict>
       <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
       <dict>
           <key>w3schools.com</key>
           <dict>
               <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
               <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
               <true/>
               <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
               <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
               <true/>
               <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
               <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
               <string>TLSv1.1</string>
           </dict>
       </dict>
   </dict>
   ```

Comment: func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        if elementName == "CelsiusToFahrenheitResult" {
            fahrenheitValue = Double(elementValue!)
            elementValue = nil
        }
    }


I have result as faultCode for elementName, so i have not get true value of fahrenheitValue , so my label, lblSonuc, is "Sonuç yok". 

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: I checked this web service on browser, now it is not working! What a luck! 
I guess i can't receive correct result because of it now. If it worked, i can get correct result, maybe..